# Binding(Converter) in Code Behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate, staticresource

```
<local:LabelTemp x:Key="labelTemplate"/>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="labelTemp">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource labelTemplate},Path=Item.Items}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Can anyone help me how to write the above Xaml code into Code Behind C#.
Im using this code into Pie Chart LabelTemplate.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't know what is the binding source, or how the Pie Chart LabelTemplate (converter) looks like. The best I can come up with that much information is the following:

```
public class LabelTemplate : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //...
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //...
    }
}
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LabelTemplate labelTemplateConverter = new LabelTemplate();
        Binding binding = new Binding("Item.Items");
        binding.Converter = labelTemplateConverter;
        txtBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);
    }
}
```

and Your textblock have the Name txtBlock

I hope this helps.