# How to set ValueConverter for DataTemplate child in code behind

Tags: uwp, datatemplate, code-behind, valueconverter

I want to access a specific control inside my `DataTemplate` and set it's `ValueConverter` from **CodeBehind**.

The `ValueConverter` should be **passed in** from the using page/control.

My **MainPage** is using **UserControls** from a different project, because they should be used in most of my applications.

The `UserControl` looks like this:

```
<Grid>
    <ListView Name="SampleListView">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Name="SampleGrid">
                    <TextBlock Name="SampleTextBox" Text="{Binding BindingProperty}" />
                    <TextBlock Name="TextBoxIWantToAccess" Foreground="{Binding SampleDateTime, Converter={StaticResource DateTimeToColorConverter}}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

So my suggestion was first to access it from code behind but it did not work...

I've tried this: 
[Binding(Converter) in Code Behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33481720/bindingconverter-in-code-behind/33482300)

in combination with this:
[WPF How to access control from DataTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586106/wpf-how-to-access-control-from-datatemplate)

but it did not work

So now my suggestion is that I could also do it like this in code

```
public MyUserControl1(IValueConverter converter)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Resources.Add("DateTimeToColorConverter", converter);
    }
```

But it did not work...

Maybe it is `... Converter={StaticResource DateTimeToColorConverter}}"` and it should not be specified as a **StaticResource** because it is from **CodeBehind**

But I tried a lot of combinations and it did not work...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <ListView>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                               Foreground="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

In code behind:

```
public MyUserControl1()
{
    this.Resources["MyConverter"] = new FooConverter();
    this.InitializeComponent();            
}
```

Note that I add the resource before calling InitializeComponent().