# How to bind IValueConverter value without using xaml in c#

Tags: c#

We are normally bind the IValueConverter value like as below,

```
<Button x:Name="myButton" Content="ClickMe" />
<Image Opacity="{Binding ElementName=myButton, Path=IsEnabled, Converter={StaticResource BoolToOpacityConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, ConverterParameter = 1}" />
```

But my requirement is, without using xaml bind the IValueConverter. Please anyone suggest me how to bind the IValueConverter using c# without using xaml

Comment: is this xamarin? if so, please tag properly~

Comment: you'd just bind it in your code behind.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33481720/bindingconverter-in-code-behind) out

Answer (score 0):

You would use it in c# exactly the same as if you were using any other class.

So if your value converter is like this:

```
public class CustomConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // ... your custom value converter                    
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
         // ... your custom value converter                              
    }
}
```

you would use it like this:

```
var customConverter = new CustomConverter();
customConverter.Convert( .. );
```

Comment: Please convert the above metioned xaml (See my xaml code) code to C#. That is I want. @Mightee

Comment: Im not gonna do your job. Search for binding in codebehind